# Querying subdirectories using drill

Tags: apache-drill

I have a parent Folder called Job_1 and i have different subdirectories from 0 -10 and in each of 0 to 10 folders i have different file called property and address.

```
  SELECT
  COUNT(LOCID)
  FROM dfs.`/Desktop/DataValidation/outputfiles/Job_1/`
  WHERE NUMBLDGS > 1
```

Job_1 has folders 0 -10 and the file is property.txt but the folder has other text files as well called accounts and so on... for a single folder the query looks like

```
  SELECT
  COUNT(LOCID)
  FROM dfs.`/Desktop/DataValidation/outputfiles/Job_1/0/property.txt`
  WHERE NUMBLDGS > 1
```

How can I run one single query against all sub directories 0 -10 and against property.txt?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can use wildcards:

```
SELECT COUNT(LOCID) FROM dfs.`/Desktop/DataValidation/outputfiles/Job_1/*/property.txt` WHERE NUMBLDGS > 1
```

Comment: THis works in drill but from Squirrel connecting to drill , * gives an error i changed the query to  SELECT COUNT(LOCID) FROM dfs.`/Desktop/DataValidation/outputfiles/Job_1/[(0-9)(0-9)?]/property.txt` WHERE NUMBLDGS > 1. if the folders have single digits after Job_1 it works but the double digit folders are ignored. \d+ OR \d* also does not give  correct count in squirrel